# Domain controller misbehaving following reboot - causing exchange not to work also

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

Kind of an urgent one.

Rebooted a few servers tonight as the backups were not completing successfully.

upon rebooting, exchange is not working at all. The errors seem to indicate that the issue is with AD, so I've looked at DC1 (Windows Server 2016) and I can see problems there...I'm guessing this is the direct cause.

I'm seeing "network logon service was not started" in the logs, however I cannot see a service what that name in services.
I'm also seeing an error in group policy like so...

```
 The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition.
```

The machine that gave that error is a domain controller itself, so thats concerning.

I belive the issue is with Ad itself and not with the Exchange.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: The first thing to try would be rebooting the Domain Controller again.  If that doesn't work, check for problems with network connectivity and DNS resolution.

Comment: The network logon service is called "Netlogon" and should be running.  If it isn't, try starting it manually and see if it generates an error code.  You should also be looking for event log errors that might be indicating why the service isn't starting successfully.

Comment: @HarryJohnston please submit this as an answer.... following an inplace upgrade from 2012 to 2016, the netlogon service was set to manual and was NOT running. Rectifying that resolved the issue.

Apparently the server hadn't rebooted in about 3 months since the upgrade was completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log message "network logon service was not started" strongly suggests a problem with the Netlogon service, so the first thing to check is whether it is running.

In the OPs case it had somehow become set for manual start, possibly due to an earlier in-place upgrade of the domain controller.  Once this was corrected the problem was resolved.  It should be noted that Microsoft [do support, but do not recommend, in-place upgrades of Domain Controllers.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/upgrade-domain-controllers)

In situations where the Netlogon service is configured to start but is failing to do so, attempting to start it manually might generate a useful error code and/or event log error messages that might provide a hint as to the underlying problem.  Process Monitor (available from the Microsoft web site) might also be a useful diagnostic tool in this scenario.